# How to generally determine if a Point is inside a Polygon/Region?

Tags: point-in-polygon

I have a region (i.e. closed polygon) like this given in cartesian coordiantes:

```
1: 628497 / 239586
2: 642383 / 249881
3: 657705 / 241262
4: 652677 / 230489
5: 631370 / 231446
6: 628497 / 239586
```

I like to know whether point `631849 / 238868` is inside this region or outside?
It would be trivial for a rectangle region, however my regions have an arbitrary shape and a lot of points.

I know, there are several working tools available to do this, for example MapInfo. However, I like to get a mathematical approach to code my own function in a common program language. A .NET assembly would help as well.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon. It's pretty straightforward, trace a ray out, calculate how many intersections it has, if odd, inside, even, outside.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716268/point-in-polygon-algorithm

Comment: All good examples, but in practice, it helps to allow a tiny margin of error (epsilon).  Otherwise floating point issues mean that, for instance, a point you calculate that should lie on a segment will fail to detect as intersecting the polygon about half the time.

Comment: @RussellatISC: Good point. In floating point calculations, one should always be alert to cases of "near zero" or "almost infinity". In cases like point-in-polygon, or other boolean-returning geometry functions, it may be better to ask "how far/close" then assess against a threshold. It is why functions like st_dwithin() are so useful; it specifically requires a threshold.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a mathematical approach", a ".NET assembly", and how are those two related?

Comment: @martinf, I like to write a small application in C# .NET. I can write it from scratch, for this I need the mathematical method. This question is answered by the comments. However, most probably somebody else around the world coded such a program already, which I could re-use. By google I found [DotSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/), however this looks fairly big and oversized for my problem.